# make a spark rdd from tuples list and use groupByKey

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a list of tuples like below

```
ls=[('c', 's'),('c', 'm'), ('c', 'p'), ('h', 'bi'), ('h', 'vi'), ('n', 'l'), ('n', 'nc')]
```

I would like to use pyspark and groupByKey to produce:

```
nc=[['c','s', 'm', 'p'], ['h','bi','vi'], ['n','l', 'nc']
```

I dont know how to make a spark rdd and use groupByKey.

I tried:

```
tem=ls.groupByKey()
```

> `'list' object has no attribute 'groupByKey'`

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that error because your object is a `list` and not an `rdd`. Python lists do not have a `groupByKey()` method (as the error states).

You can first convert your list to an `rdd` using `sc.parallelize`:

```python
myrdd = sc.parallelize(ls)
nc = myrdd.groupByKey().collect()
print(nc)
#[('c',['s', 'm', 'p']), ('h',['bi','vi']), ('n',['l', 'nc'])]
```

This returns a list of tuples where the first element is the key and the second element is a list of the values. If you wanted to flatten these tuples, you can use `itertools.chain.from_iterable`:

```python
from itertools import chain
nc = [tuple(chain.from_iterable(v)) for v in nc]
print(nc)
#[('c', 's', 'm', 'p'), ('h', 'bi', 'vi'), ('n', 'l', 'nc')]
```

However, you can avoid spark completely achieve the desired result using `itertools.groupby`:

```python
from itertools import groupby, chain
ls=[('c', 's'),('c', 'm'), ('c', 'p'), ('h', 'bi'), ('h', 'vi'), ('n', 'l'), ('n', 'nc')]

nc = [
    (key,) + tuple(chain.from_iterable(g[1:] for g in list(group)))
    for key, group in groupby(ls, key=lambda x: x[0])
]
print(nc)
#[('c', 's', 'm', 'p'), ('h', 'bi', 'vi'), ('n', 'l', 'nc')]
```

Answer (score 0):

As pault mentioned, the problem here is that Spark operates on specialised *parallelized* datasets, such as an RDD. To get the exact format you're after using groupByKey you'll need to do some funky stuff with lists:

```
ls = sc.parallelize(ls)
tem=ls.groupByKey().map(lambda x: ([x[0]] + list(x[1]))).collect()
print(tem)
#[['h', 'bi', 'vi'], ['c', 's', 'm', 'p'], ['n', 'l', 'nc']]
```

However, generally its best to avoid groupByKey as it can result in a large number of shuffles. This problem could also be solved with reduceByKey using:

```
ls=[('c', 's'),('c', 'm'), ('c', 'p'), ('h', 'bi'), ('h', 'vi'), ('n', 'l'), ('n', 'nc')]
ls = sc.parallelize(ls)
tem=ls.map(lambda x: (x[0], [x[1]])).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x + y).collect()
print(tem)
```

This will scale more effectively, but note that RDD operations can start to look a little cryptic when you need to manipulate list structure.